# Is it possible to host a WordPress site entirely on Cloudfront?

Tags: cdn

I love the Cloudfront approach described here: http://www.paessler.com/blog/2011/04/12/network-monitoring-basics/hosting_a_website_through_amazon_cloudfront

I wonder if this is possible to do with caching plugins that create static html files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean, **entirely on Cloudfront**.

Cloudfront is a CDN only. It can't run any server side scripting environments (PHP or MySQL), it therefore isn't possible to host a wordpress site entirely with Cloudfront.

You could alternatively use Cloudfront to host your images to improve speed. The closest way to host a wordpress site *entirely* on Cloudfront is to use ‘**Origin Pull**’.

It is relatively easy to setup (see [this article](http://macintoshhowto.com/advanced/how-to-use-amazon-cloudfront-to-serve-your-wordpress-site.html)), but still requires a backend server (therefore not offer a saving on cost).

Comment: I was thinking that if I used caching to produce HTML files for each page then these could be origin pulled and served from Cloudfront. Essentially making the origin a back up to the static version of the site on Cloudfront.

Comment: @trnsfrmr If you setup the caching and then create an origin pull, it will be pulling the cached pages. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In terms of shear performance, it should be great.